# Does dynamodb supports atomic counter on SET operation if value is not exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I have a use case where I need to store how many people view the blog post in DynamoDB.

Lets' say I have a table like below

| blogId | Total Views. |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |

Now when a user views a new blog with ID `2` I have to store that in the table. I can do the following to achieve that:

```js
isBlogExists = dynamodbMapper.get(BlogViews,{blogId: 2})
if (isBlogExists){
   dynamodbMapper.set("totalViews", new MathematicalExpression("totalViews", "+", 1))
} else{
   dynamodbMapper.set("totalViews", 1)
}
```

Unfortunately it ends up in race condition so I planned to use the `SET` operation like this

```js
dynamodbMapper.set("totalViews", new MathematicalExpression("totalViews", "+", 1))
```

Since this item doesn't have the totalViews attribute, I am getting a error like

> No item with the key found in Table.

So does DynamoDB doesn't support incrementing numeric values on key which doesn't exist?

I could use the `ADD` operation but DynamoDB recommends to use `SET` over `ADD` ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD)).

Comment: Where are you getting the impression that you shouldn't use `ADD` for numerical values? It's perfectly fine for that.

Comment: AWS documentation suggests to use SET over ADD [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD)

Answer (score 4):

DynamoDB offers the straightforward way of using `ADD` in the UpdateExpression, but AWS generally [recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD) going with `SET` instead:

> **Note**
>
> In general, we recommend using SET rather than ADD.

I don't see why and they don't elaborate on that. If you want to follow their guidance, here is what you can do.

The straightforward `SET attr = attr + 1` falls short in some cases because it requires the attribute to exist already. The `ADD` expression assumes a default of 0 if that's not the case, `SET` doesn't.

Fortunately, we can create a default for non-existent attributes using the `if_not_exists` [function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html). Here's an example of how to use it. It assumes a table called `pk-only` with only a partition key called `PK` of type string.

```py
import boto3

TABLE_NAME = "pk-only"
TABLE_RESOURCE = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(TABLE_NAME)

def main():
    
    TABLE_RESOURCE.update_item(
        Key={"PK": "some_item"},
        UpdateExpression="SET #att = if_not_exists(#att, :start_value) + :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#att": "counter"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":inc": 1,
            ":start_value": 0
        }
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(This is an example in Python, but you should be able to adapt it to your Javascript code quite easily)